# Spivak (4.5) $c:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is continuous then $[c^1(0),\ldots,c^n(0)]=[c^1(1),\ldots,c^n(1)]$

Tags: calculus, manifolds, differential-forms

> If $c:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is continuous function and each $(c^1(t),\ldots,c^n(t))$ is a basis of of $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that  $$[c^1(0),\ldots,c^n(0)]=[c^1(1),\ldots,c^n(1)]$$

Proof: Let $c^i(0)=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}(t)c^j(t)$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Now $$ \det[c^1(0),\ldots,c^n(0)]=\det(a_{ij}(t))\det[c^1(t),\ldots,c^n(t)] .$$ Since, $c$ is continuous so $\det(a_{ij}(t))$ is continuos in $t$ and it is non-zero $\implies \det$ will not change the sign. After that I stuck. Please help.

Comment: What does  $\;[c^1(0),\ldots,c^n(0)]\;$ mean? Are those the coordinate functions of $\;c\;$ ?

Comment: Yeah, then map is $t\mapsto [c^1(t),\ldots,c^n(t)]$. This is a problem from the book Calculus on Manifolds, Spivak (Problem 4.5).

Comment: @X But then I don't understand: $\;c\;$ is a function with codomain $\;\Bbb R^{\color{red}{n^2}}\;$ , and there are only $\;n\;$ coordinates...

Comment: No, $c^i(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. So, $c(t)\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Comment: @X But you wrote that "...and each $(c^1(t),\ldots,c^n(t))$ is a basis of of $\mathbb{R}^n$...", which means  $\;c^i(t)\;$ **must be a number**, not a vector in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ ...!

Comment: How can $c^i(t)$ be a number? Any basis of $R^n$ has $n$ entries. For example, $[e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n]$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @ Now I understand what you meant. Yes, that's right. I thought you meant each singular element...I still don't understand how those can be the coordinates of $\;c\;$, though. Never mind, perhaps someone else.

Comment: Would you care to edit your post in order to elaborate on the notations used in the exercise? Notably by addressing the question of DonAntonio, but perhaps most importantly by explaining what the square brackets $\lbrack \dots \rbrack$ are supposed to mean.